# HTML5 invoke native app (ios and android)

Tags: html

I have 2 mobile apps. One develop using HTML5 and another using native code. Is it possible to using the mobile apps (HTML5) to invoke another mobile apps (native code)? Any one can provide an example or link ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) Scheme. For example, this opens the iBooks Application.

```
<a href="ibooks://">Link</a>
```

[Here is a list for native apps](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

Comment: the above example was allow mobile apps (HTML5) to invoke another mobile apps (native code)?

Comment: thanks for the reply? May i know is it possible to pass data/parameter using the provided syntax? For example, apps A will pass one String to apps b...

Comment: Yes, but the native app has to know how to handle that data. For example opening https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bomb-defuse/id464050767?mt=8 on the iphone will open the app store to an app's page.

Comment: can you provide me the html5 script example on passing the parameter to native apps?

Comment: ... its just how you build your links. You can use a querystring like `http://mycompany.com?param1=xyz&param2=abc` or you can make a custom url scheme. The key is that the native app have to be able to decode it, and that is custom to every app. The link in my answer shows some major apps and the schemes that they take.

Comment: i had try ur idea to invoke an native apps in android but it failed ... can u help to advice? It prompt me failed to activity not found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Answer (score 0):

able to solve the encountered problem. it need to change the plist file and android manifest.xml to make it work.